# JSON conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm trying to stringify a multi-array variable into a JSON string in Javascript. The

```
//i'm using functions from http://www.json.org/json2.js

var info = new Array(max);
for (var i=0; i<max; i++) {
  var coordinate = [25 , 32];
  info[i] = coordinate;
}
var result = JSON.stringify(info);
```

But result doesn't look like a JSON string at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does the result look like then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You, and many in this question, are confused about the JSON specification. The string you have is a valid JSON array.

**From json.org**

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In    various languages, this is
>     realized    as an object, record,
>     struct,    dictionary, hash table,
>     keyed list,    or associative array.
> - An ordered list    of values. In most languages, this is    realized as
>     an array, vector, list,    or
>     sequence.

Your example matches the second structure - the ordered list of values.

**Also from json.org:**

> An array is an ordered collection of
>   values. An array begins with [ (left
>   bracket) and ends with ] (right
>   bracket). Values are separated by ,
>   (comma).
>
> A value can be a string in double
>   quotes, or a number, or true or false
>   or null, or an object or an array.
>   These structures can be nested.

Doesn't leave much to the imagination.  You've got a valid JSON array there. Have fun with it. But just to be annoyingly thorough:

**From the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)**

> RFC 4627, Section 2
>
> 2)  JSON Grammar
>
> A JSON text is a sequence of
>   tokens.  The set of tokens includes
>   six    structural characters, strings,
>   numbers, and three literal names.
>
> A JSON text is a serialized object
>   or array.
>
> ```
>   JSON-text = object / array
> ```

Comment: Just chiming in to point out that this has since been obseleted by RFC 7159. A JSON text no longer needs to be an object or array. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#appendix-A

Answer (score 6):

The result looks like this for me:

```
[[25,32],[25,32],[25,32],[25,32],[25,32],[25,32],[25,32],[25,32],[25,32],[25,32]]
```

Which is fine as far as I can see. It might look a bit weird, but that is mostly because JSON is used a lot for objects, which have a slightly different notation. You can eval the string and get the array structure back though, so it looks fine to me.

Comment: JavaScript arrays are objects. However, JSON serializes them specially, just like they have their own literal syntax.

Comment: From json.org:
An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma).

So yes, it looks like the correct JSON representation of a two-dimensional array to me.

Comment: Seriously, this is not JSON - it's a valid *value* of a property within a JSON object maybe, but it's not valid JSON as written. You need to reread the specs.

Comment: According to the spec, how should a two-dimensional array with integers should look like in JSON then? I'm starting to wonder here.

Comment: @annakata, this is clearly valid JSON.  I'm not sure how anyone could disagree.  Check it out at json.org (homepage)

Comment: @ylebre - I think the confusion was that some didn't believe an array could be a top-level JSON-text (to use terminology from the RFC).

Comment: @Triptych: that is what I figured - I also figured the rest of stackoverflow would help with the correct answer, which they did :)

Comment: RFC says that an array is legal top-level JSON-text. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627

Comment: There is a difference between the "application/json" media type and ECMAScript. The former is a strict subset of the latter. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833299/can-an-array-be-top-level-json-text).