# Can an array be top-level JSON-text?

Tags: arrays, json, rfc4627

per the debate in this post: [json-conversion-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974487/json-conversion-in-javascript/974536#974536)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Yes, an array is legal as top-level JSON-text.

There are four standard documents defining JSON: [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) (which obsoletes RFC 4627), [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), and [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) (which obsoletes RFC 7159, and calls ECMA-404 normative). They differ in which top-level elements they allow, but all allow an object or an array as the top-level element.

- RFC 4627: *Object or array.* 
  "A JSON text is a serialized object or array."
- RFC 7159, RFC8259: *Any JSON value.*  
  "A JSON text is a serialized value. Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array." [Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-2)
- ECMA-404: *Any JSON value.*  
  "A  JSON  text  is  a  sequence  of  tokens  formed  from  Unicode  code  points  that  conforms  to  the  JSON  value
  grammar."

Comment: As of [this newer RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt), "A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes six structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names."

Comment: @antak What does this mean in relation to the question?

Comment: @OrestesKappa The comment is commentary on the answer and not the question, but it's spirit is now reflected in the current revision of this answer.  Succinctly: The newer RFC does not limit JSON text to an object or an array and any serialized value is allowed.

Comment: Does the term "JSON text" refer to the top-level object? It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 72):

**Yes**, but you should consider making the root an object instead in some scenarios, due to [JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx).  This is an information disclosure vulnerability based on overriding the array constructor in JavaScript.

Comment: FWIW, JSON hijacking [is not an issue for modern browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers).

Answer (score 5):

This is from the ECMAScript specification.

```
JSONText :
    JSONValue

JSONValue :
    JSONNullLiteral 
    JSONBooleanLiteral 
    JSONObject 
    JSONArray 
    JSONString 
    JSONNumber
```

Comment: This is a little misleading, though, because ECMAScript allows you to parse JSON strings that are not top-level texts.  According to the RFC, "A JSON text is a serialized object or array."

Comment: @Matthew - Weird, I wonder how Crockford feels about that. How will they reconcile the differences between the RFC and ECMA?

Comment: I just looked, and found they're aware of the difference.  From ECMAScript 5 §15.12, "The top level JSONText production of the ECMAScript JSON grammar may consist of any JSONValue rather than being restricted to being a JSONObject or a JSONArray as specified by RFC 4627."  I don't know if IETF will change the RFC.

Comment: @Matthew - Thanks for that, I was getting horribly confused. The json.org description doesn't mention the more restrictive concept of "json-text" *at all*, and the RFC's kind of vague about its significance.

Comment: This answer is about ECMAScript, but the question is about JSON. While they (deliberately) look similar, they are _different specs_.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it. Put in `[{}]`

Comment: It's even easier than that. Put in `[]` and it will validate.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
["apple","pear","banana"]
```

I store that above in MySQL DB as a string, and then have no problem doing this in my PHP:

```
  <?php

        $checkArr = json_decode($pageData[0]['pg_json']);

        echo $checkArr[0];

    ?>
```

Which yields this:

apple

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusion, seen in the other comments. The "application/json" media type allows only object or array at the top-level for JSON-text, per [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627). However, for a parser any JSON value is acceptable, as seen in the ECMAScript specification.

Update: RFC 4627 is outdated. The new RFC 7159 permits also simple values at the top-level. (Thanks,
Matthias Dieter Wallnöfer.)

Comment: Any JSON value as the top-level element is acceptable for an _ECMAScript parser_, but not for a (compliant) _JSON parser_ - important distinction.

Comment: That's an interesting distinction, but I don't understand what you're saying. What is the definition of a "(compliant) JSON parser"?

Comment: Well,  a JSON parser is a parser for the JSON grammar. While JSON looks similar to Javascript, it is a different (much simpler) grammar. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 , which describes the JSON grammar. "compliant" just means the parser actually follows the grammar (which any decent parser should).

Comment: RFC 4627 is outdated, please don't follow it any longer. The new RFC permits also simple values at the top-level.

Comment: For future readers, the newer standard is [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159).