# Formatted String to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

In my program, I'm recieving a string such as this:

`var string = '[[["540", "540"], ["570", "600"]], [["570", "570"]], [["600", "600"]], [["630", "630"]], [["660", "660"]]]';`

Now obviously this string is in perfect array format. But its a string type. Of course I could make a big function that handles the parsing and builds the array, but it'll be slow and efficient. The string is already in array format, is there an existing function that'll let me convert that to an array type? It'll always be a 3d array if it matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can handle this kind of string perfectly.

```js
var s = '[[["540", "540"], ["570", "600"]], [["570", "570"]], [["600", "600"]], [["630", "630"]], [["660", "660"]]]';

var j = JSON.parse(s);

document.write(j[0][0][0]);
```

Comment: I knew there was a simplistic solution. The string doesn't look anything like JSON format that I've seen before, but I guess it doesn't matter? Thanks!

Comment: It is valid JSON, arrays are one of allowed types, even at the top level, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833299/can-an-array-be-top-level-json-text

Comment: @Nathan This *is* JSON... Especially when JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation (hint hint)