# How to use AngularJS to call json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in myData">
{{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
</ul>
 </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("customers.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
  });
});

</script>
```

My json file is this

```
{"Name":"Peter","Country":"Germany"}, 
{"Name":"Ana","Country":"Mexico"}
```

I try to call it ,but not successful, any idea 
Thanks.......

Comment: can check your console? and post the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file's format is incorrect, it must have a top-level type. In your case, an array would be ok.

```
[
  {"Name":"Peter","Country":"Germany"}, 
  {"Name":"Ana","Country":"Mexico"}
]
```

Check this post [Can an array be top-level JSON-text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833299/can-an-array-be-top-level-json-text) for some more detail.