# Websockets returns Only string how to get a array that is in form of a string

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, rxjs

This is the first time i am working with Web sockets please pardon any error.

I am using rxjs websockets with Angular.
the data i get in the browser is something like this from the websocket

```
'[["lnkd",76.86839599398574],["mu",127.8241808237684],["msft",174.50062080196034],["yhoo",96.43342811472303]]'
```

This is data i get in console . I am not able to use ngFor on this as it is a String type data . I want to be able to get the data in form of an array or array instead of in String is this possible .

As of now i get this in broswer using `{{data | async }}` but i need it a table format using ngfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JSON string. You need to first parse it into a object using JSON.parse() as described here.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
```

Comment: is it a json it starts with  `[` instead of `{`

Comment: you have a 2 dimensional array formatted as a JSON string. Top Level Arrays are legal in JSON objects. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833299/can-an-array-be-top-level-json-text