# Incorrect type. Expected "object"

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am having this json but Visual Studio Code gives me the warning  in the title.

```
[
    {
      "title": "Book A",
      "imageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6B1bizZf6gt_7vtUZXx0cPf81u07iJf9ZPBMPn5kM_5pyIRnE",
      "description": "Cool book!",
      "price": "10",
      "id": "0.9910457947149673"
    },
    {
      "title": "Book B",
      "imageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6B1bizZf6gt_7vtUZXx0cPf81u07iJf9ZPBMPn5kM_5pyIRnE",
      "description": "Nice!",
      "price": "12",
      "id": "0.3677736742556723"
    },
    {
      "id": "0.2599869075653567",
      "title": "Αχίλλιου Πόλης",
      "imageUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
      "description": "A cool book. Everyone should buy it!",
      "price": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": "0.8862598606325078",
      "title": "xvbxb",
      "imageUrl": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6B1bizZf6gt_7vtUZXx0cPf81u07iJf9ZPBMPn5kM_5pyIRnE",
      "description": "xvcxv",
      "price": "20"
    }
]
```

Why?

Comment: Are you getting an "error" just having that open in a file tab, or do you have code that goes with it? As it is, it is hard to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 6):

The top level [JSON](https://www.json.org/) is historically expected be an object. Not an array or primitive.

In practice the enforcement of that rule varies. VSCode is reminding you that you're not looking at JSON in the most interoperable sense.

Edit:
There are various RFCs which define JSON, the historical ones are usually stricter, but have nowdays been mostly superseded.

I am at a loss as to finding an official JSON definition that enforces the 'top level item is an object' rule. I suspect it's just been the reality with regards to browser support, and other parsers for a while, so it became a de-facto standard, before being properly standardized.

See for example:
[rfc4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) [rfc7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) [rfc8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259)

Comment: This does not appear to be correct given how I read the McKeenam form in your link or from [Can an array be top-level JSON-text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3833312/1441)

Comment: That is correct, the standard docs I am finding now, as opposed to some years back, are much more permissive.

Comment: I appreciate your updates, but you have not removed your "must ... be an object", which is not true now, nor from a brief reading of those RFC documents (including the one from 2006 that states "A JSON text is a serialized object or array."). *Should* be an object is reasonable, but *must* be an object is not correct.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-json-start-with

Comment: I've gone back to the earliest mention of json I could find here: http://web.archive.org/web/20030228034147/http://www.crockford.com/JSON/index.html and even there it's not iron-clad. It appears that initial implementations of JSON shaped a de-facto rule fore the top level item to be an object.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem, and it turns out it's caused by an extension instead of VSCode itself.

Click on the icon of *Editor Language Status*, and then click *Show Schemas* to check if there is any JSON schema configured. Try to change the schema or disable related extension to see if it solves the problem.

In my case, it's caused by a JSON schema configured by extension.

[image: VSCode Editor Language Status - JSON Schema]

Comment: That was my problem as well.  In my case it was a Firebase extension that was causing the issue.